Content-Based Filtering for Internship Recommendations Without User Ratings—Is It Feasible?
I’m designing a recommendation feature for a student internship platform. Students will explicitly select their interests and skills during registration, and recruiters will post internship opportunities with associated requirements or tags (like skills, location, etc.).
Plan: I intend to use content-based filtering to match:
Student Profiles (interests, skills) Internship Opportunities (tags, descriptions) . However, many examples I’ve read involve matrices of user-item ratings or feedback.
Questions:
1-Do I need a ratings matrix for content-based filtering, or can this method work solely by comparing attributes?
2-Is an external dataset required, or will using internally generated data (from user profiles and internships) suffice?
I’m currently in the planning phase and haven’t started coding, but I want to ensure this design is viable. Any guidance or clarification would be appreciated!

Be aware of GenAI tools generated contents regardless of reputation of answer provider. See this screenshot I could generated super similar answer using ChatGPT 4o

Welcome to Data Science Stack Exchange @Amira :) It is good that you are thinking ahead during the planning stage. Your proposed recommendation system for a student internship platform using content-based filtering (CBF) seems feasible to me, and is well-aligned with your use case. Following, I will try to address your concerns:

1. Do I need a ratings matrix for content-based filtering, or can this method work solely by comparing attributes?

Content-based filtering does not require a ratings matrix. Unlike collaborative filtering, which relies on user-item interactions (eg., ratings or feedback), CBF uses attributes of users and items to compute similarity. For your case:

Student Profiles: Represented as feature vectors of interests and skills.
Internship Opportunities: Represented as vectors of tags and descriptions.

Similarity Measures
CBF compares profiles using mathematical similarity measures, such as:

Cosine Similarity:
$$
   \text{Similarity}(A, B) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} A_i B_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} A_i^2} \cdot \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} B_i^2}}
   $$
Ideal for numerical data, such as tag frequencies, where values are normalised to a common scale.

Jaccard Similarity:
$$
   \text{Similarity}(A, B) = \frac{|A \cap B|}{|A \cup B|}
   $$
Suitable for binary features (eg., skill tags).

TF-IDF (Term Frequency–Inverse Document Frequency):
Represent textual descriptions as weighted vectors using:
$$
   \text{TF-IDF}(t, d) = \text{TF}(t, d) \cdot \log\left(\frac{N}{\text{DF}(t)}\right)
   $$
where:

$t$: term
$d$: document
$N$: total documents
$\text{DF}(t)$: documents containing $t$




2. Is an external dataset required, or will using internally generated data suffice?

External data are certainly useful in this context, but internally generated data should be sufficient, provided that:

Students provide explicit interests and skills during registration, and
Recruiters assign detailed tags or descriptions to postings.

External Enhancements
External datasets can further improve the system by:

Synonym Mapping: Recognising equivalent terms (eg., "machine learning" vs. "AI").
Pre-trained Models: Embedding textual data into vector spaces using tools like Word2Vec or Sentence-BERT for nuanced comparisons.

Recommendations for Implementation
Data Preprocessing

Standardisation: Normalise terms (eg., "Python" vs. "python").
Ontologies: Map hierarchical relationships (eg., "data science" includes "machine learning").

Scalability

Use sparse matrix representations for efficiency.
Implement fast similarity searches with tools like FAISS (Facebook AI Similarity Search).

Cold Start Problem
For new users or internships:

Provide default recommendations based on generalised profiles or popular internships.

Incorporating Feedback
Even without explicit ratings:

Collect implicit feedback (eg., clicks, applications).
Use this data to adjust feature weights and refine matching over time.

Summing Up
Content-based filtering is a viable approach for your internship recommender platform. It does not require a ratings matrix and can work effectively with internally generated data. For improved scalability and accuracy:

Start with simple attribute-based matching.
Incrementally enhance using feedback and external datasets.

References

Lops, P., Gemmis, M., & Semeraro, G. (2011). "Content-based Recommender Systems: State of the Art and Trends." DOI:10.1007/s10462-010-9198-6
Manning, C., Raghavan, P., & Schütze, H. (2008). Introduction to Information Retrieval. Online
Johnson, J., Douze, M., & Jégou, H. (2019). "Billion-scale similarity search with GPUs." FAISS


Thank you so much , i read that if i used cosine similarity to measure the similarity it wouldn’t be considered Ai is that correct?

@Robert Long , Please consider the right way of Gen-AI tools and if you used their content you need to put the in quote and notedown which GenAI tools and LLM model and query have you used and put the date you accessed this content. Don't delete your answers but edit it.  I raised flag for moderator because of copy the content from GenAI tools without owning this content and slight contribution in start of your post.  This is bad for your reputation. Your "References" at the end of post is not clear address for which part of your answer.

see this screenshot I could generated super similar answer using ChatGPT 4o
